# Usage of WndProc for receiving message from skype

Tags: c#, winforms, skype, wndproc

i am trying hard to capture & save skype conversation to file. i go through this tutorial **http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2011/08/27/how-to-record-skype-voice-conversations.aspx** also download wpf based the source code which i run and got the success.

i follow the everything but my application is not working. the main problem is regarding receiving message from skype through `WndProc()` function. my `WndProc()` function is calling only once but the application which i download there i saw their `WndProc()` function is calling repeatedly for getting message from skype. i am trying for long time to capture the skype conversation but still no luck.

i already post few questions for capturing the skype conversation in this forum but not getting no expected clue. here i attach the link of my win application and that is https://onedrive.live.com/#cid=C4A6F16F34D7540A&id=C4A6F16F34D7540A!126 just download the skypecalltest and run it and definitely notice that `WndProc()` function is calling repeatedly for getting message from skype.

here is my `WndProc()` body

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            Boolean handled = false;
            if (m.Msg == NativeCalls.APIAttach && (uint)m.LParam == NativeCalls.SKYPECONTROLAPI_ATTACH_SUCCESS)
            {
                // Get the current handle to the Skype window
                NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST = m.WParam;
                handled = true;
                m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
            }

            // Skype sends our program messages using WM_COPYDATA. the data is in lParam
            if (m.Msg == NativeCalls.WM_COPYDATA && m.WParam == NativeCalls.HWND_BROADCAST)
            {
                COPYDATASTRUCT data = (COPYDATASTRUCT) Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
                StatusTextBox.Items.Add(data.lpData + Environment.NewLine);

                // Check for connection
                //if (data.lpData.IndexOf("CONNSTATUS ONLINE") > -1)
                //    ConnectButton.IsEnabled = false;

                // Check for calls
                IsCallInProgress(data.lpData);
                handled = true;
                m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
            }
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (handled) DefWndProc(ref m); else base.WndProc(ref m);

        }
```

please please help me to capture the problem and guide me where i need to rectify as a result `WndProc()` should work as expected. thanks

Comment: anybody can help my friend coz he is in serious trouble.